# What is a "Respect-Ban"?

Tags: dota-2

I was watching some replays from The International 2 and the caster used this word sometimes - especially when the teams have chosen their 4th and 5th ban.
What exactly is a "respect-ban"?

Comment: I believe it's just a ban targeted toward a specific player as a sign of acknowledgement of that player's skill at a specific hero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Respect bans are bans of heroes that are generally not considered strong in the current metagame but which are run extremely well by a specific player. Examples are Dendi's Pudge, Puppey's Chen, Korok's Morphling, Sylar's Lone Druid, etc.